# Creating QT UI for multiple tabs and initial combobox

Tags: qt, user-interface, tabs, qt-connection

My setup is as follows:

```
main.cpp
projectQt.cpp
projectQt.h
tab1.h
tab1.cpp
tab2.h
tab2.cpp
projectQt.ui
ui_projectQt.h
```

I want to create a project with a UI file. In the UI file, I have three comboBoxes and two Apply buttons and in the tab1.cpp and tab2.cpp, I want to add the initial Items of the comboboxes. If the user clicks one of the Apply buttons, run the "OnBtnApplyClicked" methods.

However I get this error:

```
projectQt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Ctab1::~Ctab1(void)" (??1Ctab1@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ProjectQt::ProjectQt(class QWidget *)" (??0ProjectQt@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
C:\output\Deneme\Qt\Win32\Debug\\projectQt.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "projectQt.h"

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ProjectQt w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

projectQt.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ProjectQtClass</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="ProjectQtClass">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>900</width>
    <height>900</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>ProjectQt</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>800</width>
      <height>800</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="IDC_FORM_TAB_1">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>M001</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="IDC_LBL_1_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>40</y>
        <width>124</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>COMBO1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="IDC_CMB_1_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>120</x>
        <y>40</y>
        <width>69</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="IDC_CMB_1_1">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>120</x>
        <y>90</y>
        <width>69</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="IDC_BTN_1_Apply">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>180</x>
        <y>174</y>
        <width>75</width>
        <height>23</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Apply</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="IDC_LBL_1_1">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>90</y>
        <width>124</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>COMBO2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="IDC_FORM_TAB_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>M002</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="IDC_LBL_2_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>30</y>
        <width>104</width>
        <height>13</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>COMBO3</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="IDC_CMB_2_0">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>100</x>
        <y>30</y>
        <width>69</width>
        <height>22</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="IDC_BTN_2_Apply">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>100</x>
        <y>70</y>
        <width>75</width>
        <height>23</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Apply</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>900</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="projectQt.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

projectQt.cpp file:

```
#include "projectQt.h"
#include "tab1.h"
#include "tab2.h"
#include "ui_projectQt.h"

ProjectQt::ProjectQt(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    
    Ctab1 ctab11;
    Ctab1 ctab22;
    ctab11.initGUI();
    ctab22.initGUI();
    
    connect(ui.IDC_BTN_1_Apply,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Ctab1::OnBtnApplyClicked()));
    connect(ui.IDC_BTN_2_Apply,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Ctab2::OnBtnApplyClicked()));

}

ProjectQt::~ProjectQt()
{

}
```

projectQt.h file:

```
#ifndef projectQt_H
#define projectQt_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_projectQt.h"
#include "tab1.h"
#include "tab2.h"

class ProjectQt : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ProjectQt(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ProjectQt();

//private:
    Ui::ProjectQtClass ui;
};

#endif // projectQt_H
```

tab1.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "projectQt.h"
#include "ui_projectQt.h"

class Ctab1
{
    
public:
    Ctab1(void);
    ~Ctab1(void);

public slots:
    void setEvents();
    void initGUI();
    void OnBtnApplyClicked();

//private:
    //Ui::ProjectQtClass *ui;
    
};
```

tab1.cpp file:

```
#include "projectQt.h"
#include "tab1.h"
#include <QTextStream>
#include "ui_projectQt.h"

Ctab1::Ctab1(void)
{
}

void Ctab1::initGUI(){
    Ui::ProjectQtClass uimain;
    uimain.IDC_CMB_1_0->addItem("1100");
    uimain.IDC_CMB_1_0->addItem("1101");
    uimain.IDC_CMB_1_1->addItem("1200");
    uimain.IDC_CMB_1_1->addItem("1201");
    
}

void Ctab1::OnBtnApplyClicked(){
    
}
```

tab2.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "projectQt.h"
#include "ui_projectQt.h"

class Ctab2
{
    
public:
    Ctab2(void);
    ~Ctab2(void);

public slots:
    void setEvents();
    void initGUI();
    void OnBtnApplyClicked();
    
//private:
    //Ui::ProjectQtClass *ui;
    
};
```

tab2.cpp file:

```
#include "projectQt.h"
#include "tab2.h"
#include <QTextStream>
#include "ui_projectQt.h"

Ctab2::Ctab2(void)
{
}

void Ctab2::initGUI(){
    
    Ui::ProjectQtClass uimain;
    uimain.IDC_CMB_2_0->addItem("2000");
    uimain.IDC_CMB_2_0->addItem("2001");
    
}

void Ctab2::OnBtnApplyClicked(){
        
}
```

Comment: You won't specified what error exactly you has.

Comment: Thanks. Now just check out the answer of @RobbieE below, i think this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see an error along the lines of "undefined reference ...", it means it's a linker error.

This particular error means that somewhere in your program, the destructor for the `Ctab1` class is being called but it can't find the implementation of that destructor in any of your source files, only the declaration.

Add the following to your `tab1.cpp` file:

```
Ctab1::~Ctab1(){
   // any cleanup code placed here
}
```

It also seems clear that you don't fully understand variable scope in C++. (`ctab11` and `ctab22` only exist inside the constructor of `ProjectQt`

I suggest you take an introductory course in C/C++ before carrying on with your project.